# Ansible 2.0 os_user Module Create User Error: Failed to list users

Tags: ansible, openstack, ubuntu-16.04

Im trying automate openstack istallation in ubuntu using ansible. For Identity service (keystone Installation),

My task is to create a user "demo",    The command to do this is

```
   openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt demo
```

and im using os_user module,
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/os_user_module.html for creating user.

```
   - os_user:
       name: demo
       password: DEMO_PASS
       domain: default
       wait: yes
       state: present
     environment: "{{ admin_openrc }}"
```

and the host is,

```
     - hosts: controller
       roles:
         - install_keystone
       tags:
         - keystone
       vars:
        admin_openrc:
          OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME: Default
          OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME: Default
          OS_PROJECT_NAME: admin
          OS_USERNAME: admin
          OS_PASSWORD: ADMIN_PASS
          OS_AUTH_URL: http://controller:35357/v3
          OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION: 3
          OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION: 2
        demo_openrc:
          OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME: Default
          OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME: Default
          OS_PROJECT_NAME: demo
          OS_USERNAME: demo
          OS_PASSWORD: DEMO_PASS
          OS_AUTH_URL: http://controller:5000/v3
          OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION: 3
          OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION: 2
```

But when im running the playbook,Im getting the following error,

```
    "msg": "Failed to list users"
```

and the module fails with error.

when i run the command directly in terminal, its working fine.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
vars:
    auth_dict:
      password: admin-pw
      auth_url: http://your-url/your-version
      username: admin
```

use auth paramter with os_user:

```
tasks:
   - os_user:
       auth: '{{ auth_dict }}'
       name: your-user
       password: your-password
```